# Input function terminating program

Tags: python, if-statement

For the life of me I can not figure out what is going to with my program. What I want to happen is if the input for my program is correct for it to move on to another choice. But when I input the intended correct input my program terminates. Please help!

```
print('''
*******************************************************************************
          |                   |                  |                     |
 _________|________________.=""_;=.______________|_____________________|_______
|                   |  ,-"_,=""     `"=.|                  |
|___________________|__"=._o`"-._        `"=.______________|___________________
          |                `"=._o`"=._      _`"=._                     |
 _________|_____________________:=._o "=._."_.-="'"=.__________________|_______
|                   |    __.--" , ; `"=._o." ,-"""-._ ".   |
|___________________|_._"  ,. .` ` `` ,  `"-._"-._   ". '__|___________________
          |           |o`"=._` , "` `; .". ,  "-._"-._; ;              |
 _________|___________| ;`-.o`"=._; ." ` '`."\` . "-._ /_______________|_______
|                   | |o;    `"-.o`"=._``  '` " ,__.--o;   |
|___________________|_| ;     (#) `-.o `"=.`_.--"_o.-; ;___|___________________
____/______/______/___|o;._    "      `".o|o_.--"    ;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/_"=._o--._        ; | ;        ; ;/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/__"=._o--._   ;o|o;     _._;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/____"=._o._; | ;_.--"o.--"_/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/______/_____"=.o|o_.--""___/______/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/_____ /
*******************************************************************************
''')
print("Welcome to Treasure Island.")
print("Your mission is to find the treasure.")

# https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Treasure%20Island%20Conditional.drawio#Uhttps%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fid%3D1oDe4ehjWZipYRsVfeAx2HyB7LCQ8_Fvi%26export%3Ddownload

# Write your code below this line 
correct_choice = False
correct_choice1 = False
choice_1 = input('Welcome to Treasure Island. Your Mission is to find treasure!\nYou are presented a crossroad, and you can choose left or right. Choose wisely.')
x = choice_1.lower
if x == 'right':
    print('You get eaten by an Owlbear, game over')
elif x == 'left':
    correct_choice == True
    destiny = input('as you walk along the crossroad you are confronted with a passage going to a cave and another to a village. Type cave or village respectively,')

if correct_choice and destiny.lower == 'village':
    print('Because you are Jesus Christ, the villagers crucify you (they are Roman).')
elif correct_choice and destiny.lower == 'village':
    correct_choice1 == True
    button = input('When you enter the cave you are presented with 3 buttons, Which do you choose Blue, Red, or Green')

if correct_choice and correct_choice1 and button.lower == 'blue' or 'red':
    print('The Sword of Damocles falls upon your head and your life comes to an end')
elif correct_choice and correct_choice1 and button.lower == 'green':
    print('You have won! The Treasure is yours!')
```

Comment: You should __learn__ about loops and how to use them.

Comment: Your program terminates because it has a finite number of instructions and it has gone through all of them. There is no loop (as mentioned above), so it will not loop. What did you input exactly and what did you expect from it?

Comment: side note; lower() is a function ,  you are missing parentheses